# Div disappear after hover ended on bootstrap tooltips

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I think how I have a very basic question for bootstrap ninja, but I really can't figure out what is problem in a past two hours, and this start to be annoying for me.

I'm using twitter tool tips on a next way:

HTML:

```
 <div>
 <span class="Haris" data-toogle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="My test My test">MY DIV TEXT</span>
 </div>
```

jQuery:

```
($j)(function () {
    ($j)('.Haris').tooltip();
});
```

Now, what is exactly a problem? Problem is when hover ended on tooltip than tooltip disappear (which is expected behavior) but also whole div disappear. I was looking what happens when hover ended and I saw how some and somehow set to  attribute display: none; after hovering ended.

Any kind of help is welcome.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT: I had figure out how I have some conflict between bootstrap tooltips and mootools-more.js, but still I didn't resolve it...**

**EDIT 2: I was take a look onto 'call stack', and right there I convince myself how motools-more.js causes this problem.**

Here is screen shot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z9V4.png

Now, I ask you. Is there any way to change this ( its better to say override it) without any modifications of motools-more.js directly?

Thanks

Comment: you want to set display: none to your parent div? or like this? ($j)('.Haris').tooltip().css('display','none');

Comment: Nope, you didn't understand me. I have a problem why div with classname = Haris automatically disappear. I found out how there is some conflict with mootools-more.js and bootstrap tooltips, but still I can't find a solution..

Comment: i have the same problem. i was adding tooltip to dynamically added element. the tooltip would show after hovering on the element/icon <a> tag, then the icon will disappear also :( and i saw a 'display:none' being added in the inline styles, but idk where its from.